# Drawing triangles within CGRect frame cutting off third point

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawing, cgrect

I'm trying to draw a triangle within a rectangle frame. I'm using two hand-gesture points startPoint and endPoint and calculating the thirdPoint (making the triangle equilateral). Drawing the triangle works fine the problem is that the frame that hold the rectangle size is base on the area of the hand-gesture so sometimes the third point gets cut off and does not show see bellow:

[image]

Is there any way I can add that third point so the frame so it takes it in consideration and does not get cut off.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. You start off with 2 points, calculate the third one and then draw the triangle? Are you sure you are not trying to draw outside the rect?

Comment: yes, but the third point gets calculated the user never touches that area and the rectangle that holds it glows as your finger goes over it.

Comment: there is no reason for it to be getting cut off, we need to see how you are drawing your triangle since the way you are setting the frame in relation to the user moving of fingers is the problem.